# Build custom EDID with several modelines

Tags: kernel, compiling, monitors, edid

I would like to build custom EDID using [kernel sources](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/edid).

But I need to use several modelines - more refresh rates for same resolution.

Is it possible using method in kernel sources? Could you please show me how my `1920x1080.S` file should look like?